# Can XMPP be used like Comet's http long wait?

Tags: ajax, comet, xmpp, reverse-ajax

Can [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) be applied in a similar way to the [reverse Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Ajax) pattern? Can it be used to implement http long wait like [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))? Is there an example of using such a technique with XMPP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Take a look at [XMPP over BOSH](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html). It's a long-lived non-polling technique. From the [BOSH specification](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html):

> This specification defines a transport protocol that emulates the semantics of a long-lived, bidirectional TCP connection between two entities (such as a client and a server) by efficiently using multiple synchronous HTTP request/response pairs without requiring the use of frequent polling or chunked responses.

[jbosh](http://kenai.com/projects/jbosh/pages/Home) is an open source Java implementation. [Tigase.org](http://www.tigase.org/) has a number of projects, including BOSH support, and appears to be mostly Java/GWT. [JAXMPP](http://www.tigase.org/en/project/jaxmpp) is a Java library in the framework, although it's not clear what feature set it supports. I've not tried any of these myself.

Comment: @cometta: I've added Java links to the revised answer.

Comment: can you comment on benefit of using xmpp bosh approach compared with comet ? which stand out better?

Comment: @cometta: I think that is a detailed enough discussion to require its own question.

Answer (score 3):

- Like Ire told you can use bosh for that. On the client-side(javascript) you could use [strophe.js](http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/).
- [Prosody](http://prosody.im/) is an easy to install XMPP-server which supports BOSH.
- To learn how to create programs using strophe.js you could read [Professional XMPP programming with javascript and Jquery](http://professionalxmpp.com/)